# Поиск частоты встречаемости числа

Tags: алгоритм, олимпиада

**Есть задача, описанная ниже.** Каким бы способом вы бы решили её?  Моя мысль заключается в создании двухмерного массива, но, очевидно, что я мыслю в данный момент неправильно.

На вход подается **N** - количество строк, которые будут введены в программу. Сразу после ввода N вводятся определенные значения **K - индификатор студента (ID). Значение К может быть очень велико.** Если встречается K c определенным значением, например, 1043, то мы должны увеличить личную переменную студента Count на единицу. 
 
**Задача:** вывести максимальный Count и соответствующий ему ID.  
Пример ввода: 
5 
1029 
1011 
1029 
8 
78

**Вывод:**
2 1029

**Иными словами, нужно определить, какое число встречается чаще всех и вывести значение, сколько раз встретилось это число.**

**Вопросы**: 
 
**1)** Каким образом лучше реализовать эту задачу? Можно ли обойтись без создания огромного двухмерного массива? 
 
**2)** Какие вообще есть варианты решения задачи кроме самого оптимального, описанного Вами в пункте 1)

**UPD**: Очевидно, что решить задачу можно с использованием динамических структур данных вроде хэш-таблиц или деревьев. Ответ с рекомендацией использовать динамические структуры приемлем, **однако меня интересует решение задачи с использованием стандартных средств языка без создания собственных структур.**

Comment: Ну так `unordered_map` - вполне стандартное средство языка С++ :) Кстати, а зачем вам **двумерный** массив?

Comment: Если требуется лишь `вывести максимальный Count и соответствующий ему ID`, то отсортировать и за один просмотр найти (по ходу чтения всех ID ничего искать и увеличивать не надо)

Comment: _с использованием стандартных средств языка_ - деревья и Хэш таблицы входят в стандартную библиотеку

Comment: О стандартных средствах какого именно языка речь? В JavaScript, например, задача элементарно решается при помощи объектов - совершенно базовой структуры языка.

Comment: @Harry Благодарю за идею, да, так и есть. Однако предполагается, что эта задача школьного уровня. Не думаю, что школьник может иметь представление о сложных структурах данных вроде хэш-таблиц, деревьев и unordered_map.

Comment: Скорее школьник может не знать, что скрывается за ними, какие алгоритмы... Но даже если так - то отлично подходит идея @avp.

Comment: @avp, может, оформите как ответ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я решил вашу задачу следующим образом, используя язык С++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int n;
    cout << "-> N: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    int *arr_ptr; 
    arr_ptr = new int[n];
    // Вводим все элементы в массив
    for (int i(0); i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> *(arr_ptr + i);
    }
    for (int i(1); i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j(0); j < n-i; j++)
        {
            if (*(arr_ptr + j) < *(arr_ptr + j + 1))
            {
                int temp = *(arr_ptr + j);
                *(arr_ptr + j) = *(arr_ptr + j + 1);
                *(arr_ptr + j + 1) = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "OK" << endl;
    int max = -1;
    cout << "Показываю отсортированный массив: " << endl;
    for (int i(0); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (*(arr_ptr + i) > max)
            max = *arr_ptr + i;
        cout << *(arr_ptr + i) << " ";
    }
    int count = 0;
    for (int i(0); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (*(arr_ptr+i) == max)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << count << " " << max << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```